# How to setup routes.MapRoute with a custom route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Using asp.net MVC 3, I have in Global.asax

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

I would like the route be from CustomRouteHandler.

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        CustomHttpHandler handler = new CustomHttpHandler(requestContext);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

How do I change my routes.MapRoute code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
routes.Add(new Route("CustomPath", new CustomRouteHandler()));
```

Or:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("CustomPath", new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Routes.MapRoute` is really just a shorthand method. In case you have a custom handler you can't use the shortcut, you have to use the `add`-method:

```
Route specialroute= new Route("path", new CustomRouteHandler());
routes.Add("special", specialroute);
```